# Issues calling AsyncTask from SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, android-asynctask

My current Android project utilizes an SQLite database. According to documentation available on the subject, database operations can be long running depending on the size of the database, and therefore the use of AsyncTask is recommended, particularly for large data sets. I have thus implemented operations within my database class as AsyncTasks:

```java
package com.hadleyresearch.apptest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class TscDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    final private Context db_context;

    //Action Strings
    public static final String DEVICE_LIST_AVAILABLE =
            "com.hadleyresearch.apptest.DEVICE_LIST_AVAILABLE";
    public static final String FUNCTION_LIST_AVAILABLE =
            "com.hadleyresearch.apptest.FUNCTION_LIST_AVAILABLE";
    public static final String DEVICE_PROFILE_AVAILABLE =
            "com.hadleyresearch.apptest.DEVICE_PROFILE_AVAILABLE";

    public TscDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db_context = context;
        // An alternate constructor can be used here to specify a
        // different database location, such as an SD card. This folder
        // must be available and permissions must be included to write
        // to it.
        //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private class ListDevices extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            String sqlTable = "Devices";
            String[] sqlColumns = {"_id", "deviceAddr", "deviceName", "deviceType"};
            Cursor c = db.query(sqlTable, sqlColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_LIST_AVAILABLE, result);
            db.close();
        }

    }

    public class GetDevice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        protected Cursor doInBackground(String... device) {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            String sqlTable = "Devices";
            //String[] sqlColumns = {"_id", "deviceAddr", "deviceName", "deviceType"};
            String[] sqlColumns = null;
            String sqlWhere = "deviceProfile = ?";
            String[] whereArgs = new String[] {device.toString()};
            Cursor c = db.query(sqlTable, sqlColumns, sqlWhere, whereArgs, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_PROFILE_AVAILABLE, result);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    //TODO - Implement listFunctions() command
    // listFunctions() - list out mappable TactSense Functions
    private class ListFunctions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            String sqlTable = "Functions";
            String[] sqlColumns = {"_id", "FunctionID", "FunctionName"};
            Cursor c = db.query(sqlTable, sqlColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            broadcastUpdate(FUNCTION_LIST_AVAILABLE, result);
            db.close();
        }

    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(db_context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final Cursor cursor) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtras(cursor.getExtras());
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(db_context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

After that, I call the AsyncTask from within a service:

```js
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        initialize();
        db = new TscDatabase(this);
        new db.GetDevice().execute(device);
        return mBinder;
    }
```

Android Studio is seemingly aware of the existence of GetDevice as a method of db, as it offers it to me as an autocomplete example. Once autocompleted, however, it highlights it in red and gives me the error "Cannot resolve symbol GetDevice". I tried cleaning the project, to no avail.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class-structure is not completely clear, but this should work:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    initialize();
    db = new TscDatabase(this);
    TscDatabase.GetDevice asyncDev = new TscDatabase.GetDevice();
    asyncDev.execute(device);
    return mBinder;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the "Cannot Resolve Symbol" error, however implementing the above code throws the following error: 

'com.hadleyresearch.apptest.TscDatabase' is not an enclosing class

Comment: Then please add TscDatabase's code in the question.

Comment: @Gaurav: Home from work; added the full code for TscDatabase to the question. Any help you or others can render would be most appreciated, thanks.